# Does submitting 'URL and all linked pages' help with new website indexing?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I am aware that sitemaps are one way to provide lists of page URLs to Google bots.

However, Google webmaster allows one to fetch a page as Google and to submit the 'URL and all linked pages'. Does this accelerate new website indexing (assuming the fetched page contains links other pages on the site) or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *can* accelerate indexing in some edge cases (I'm thinking of a site overhaul with new or additional content or URLs) but it doesn't really do anything all that different from the sitemap submission for purposes of indexing.  The better way to think of Fetch is that it makes Google aware you want to be (re)indexed but it's more of a polite request on bended knee than a command from on high.

If you have published a sitemap, the Googlebot will find you.  If you submit via Fetch, the Googlebot will find you.